# Does the order of the cipher suit in FF and IE configurations matter

Tags: security, firefox, ssl, network-programming, network-protocols

In SSL connections. As far as I understand that the the order of the cipher suit that the client offers to the server matters. How can I know what is the order of the client's offered cipher suit in my Firefox or IE browsers?

In FF, I tried to type `about:config` and then filtered the output to: security.ssl, I got:

[image]

Is this is the exact order that the client offers to SSL servers? Does this means, my browser prefers DHE and ECDHE over RSA key exchange because the DHE and ECDHE ciphers came first?

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network because its not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](https://www.superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in the TLS RFC that says the order matters. Specific servers may choose to honor the order provided by the client as an order of preference, but it isn't required, and neither JSSE not OpenSSL does so to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Thanks. If you can provide more details about the servers practices in this matter? i.e. Do servers selection behavior depends on the OS (windows servers vs. Linux or Unix). I need to get deep understanding of how servers select cipher suite?

Comment: Regarding JSSE, I believe Java 8 is different than Java 7 in the server cipher suite preference. See this blog: http://blog.ivanristic.com/2014/03/ssl-tls-improvements-in-java-8.html under the server cipher suite preference which says in Java 7, the first cipher suit offered by Java client was selected. But in Java 8, the Server has the control to specify cipher suit preference. What do you think?

Comment: Hadn't seen that but it's a good improvement. You can do that in OpenSSL too, and therefore in Apache HTTPD. But note that this still has nothing to do with the order presented by the client.